# Programmatically created UITableView with non self datasource & delegates

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I'd like to use an instance of a separate class as my UITableView's datasource & delegate. I create a new instance of the class that should handle this role and assign it via my tableview's properties:

autoMakesTable is defined as property:

```
var autoMakesTable : UITableView?
```

Further down:

```
    func nextBttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch self.autoState {

    case .NewOrEdit:

        self.autoState = .YearEntered

        // If the picker wasn't used create a new Auto with the default year value
        self.auto = Auto(year: NSNumber(integerLiteral: self.yearPickerValues.count - 2), make: "", model: "", body: "", trim: "", downPaymentBudget: 0, monthlyPaymentBudget: 0)

        // Prepare the make & model fields
        backgroundFieldView                     = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0-self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/2))
        backgroundFieldView!.backgroundColor    = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 251/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1.0)

        let makeField           = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 100, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 34, 200, 30))
        makeField.delegate      = self
        makeField.placeholder   = "Make"
        makeField.addTarget(self, action: Selector("makeTextChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

        let modelField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 100, makeField.frame.origin.y + makeField.frame.size.height + 8, 200, 30))
        modelField.placeholder = "Model"

        let newAutoMakesTableData = AutoMakesTableData()

        autoMakesTable = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(makeField.frame.origin.x, makeField.frame.origin.y + makeField.frame.height + 2, makeField.frame.width, 100))
        autoMakesTable!.dataSource    = newAutoMakesTableData
        autoMakesTable!.delegate      = newAutoMakesTableData
        self.backgroundFieldView?.addSubview(self.autoMakesTable!)
        self.autoMakesTable!.reloadData()

        makeField.becomeFirstResponder()

        self.addBorderToTextField([makeField,modelField])

        self.view.addSubview(backgroundFieldView!)

        // Move year picker with animation
        // Update next button location while loading make / model input fields with animation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.newYearPicker?.frame.origin.y = 0
            self.backgroundFieldView!.frame.origin.y = 0
            self.backgroundFieldView!.addSubview(makeField)
            self.backgroundFieldView?.addSubview(modelField)
//self.backgroundFieldView?.addSubview(self.autoMakesTable!)
//                self.autoMakesTable!.reloadData()
        })

    case .YearEntered:
        self.autoState = .MakeModelEntered

    case .MakeModelEntered:
        self.autoState = .DetailsEntered

    case .DetailsEntered:
        self.autoState = .BudgetEntered
    case .BudgetEntered:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)

    }

}
```

It's added onto the view hierarchy (I intact see an empty tableview with a few rows) later on. I also try to call reloadData() on it to no effect.

AutoMakesTableData is defined like so:

```
import UIKit

class AutoMakesTableData: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

// Auto makes URL
// This should be hosted online so changes can be made w/out having to re-submit the app
let urlForMakes = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("makes", withExtension: "JSON")
var autoMakes : [String]?

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.populateAutoMakesFromURL(urlForMakes!)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    print("cell created")

    return aCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected row")
}

private func populateAutoMakesFromURL(url: NSURL) {

    do {

        let jsonAutoMakesData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)

        do {

            let jsonAutoMakes = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonAutoMakesData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:[String]]

            self.autoMakes = jsonAutoMakes["makes"]
            // Sort array alphabetically
            self.autoMakes?.sortInPlace(<)

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error.userInfo.debugDescription)
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.userInfo.debugDescription)

    }

}

}
```

I can access the autoMakes array property on this instance without a problem.

The table view shows up but none of the print statements fire (for a cell at index path or for did select row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you install the table view into the view hierarchy. If you don't install the view controller into the active view hierarchy it won't do anything.

That is my guess as to what's going wrong.

It's ok to have a separate object serve as the data source/delegate of the view controller.

### EDIT:

Based on discussion below this answer, it turns out the problem was that the OP was creating his AutoMakesTableData in a method and assigning it to a local variable but not saving any other strong references to it.

When the method that created the AutoMakesTableData object returned, the local variable went out of scope, there were no more strong references to the object, and it was deallocated.
A table view's delegate and dataSource properties are weak, so those get zeroed out when the object is deallocated. The table view no longer has a data source, so nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, it is installed later on in the file, updating the question now.

Comment: Also show the context where you create the newAutoMakesTableData variable. Somebody needs a strong reference to that object or it will be deallocated. Your post makes it look like it's a local variable, which means that as soon as it goes out of scope, it gets deallocated, and the datasource & delegate properties of the table view will be set to nil (they are weak references).

Comment: I've added the context of the code. I've also tried it outside of the animation closure (just above it) with no effect.

Comment: Show the entire method that defines newAutoMakesTableData, and tell us what class that method is defined in. It looks to me like the line `let newAutoMakesTableData = AutoMakesTableData()` defines `newAutoMakesTableData` as a local variable but you never assign it to a strong property or instance variable. If that's true, as soon as that method returns, `newAutoMakesTableData` will be deallocated.

Comment: That's it exactly, thank you. As soon as I made an instance property for newAutoMakesTableData and assigned the tableview properties to that property it all worked.

Comment: Yup. The takeaway is that every object that you want to live needs to be owned by somebody that sticks around. If you create an object and the only strong reference is a local variable, the object goes away as soon you leave the scope of that local variable and the strong reference is released.

Comment: Thank you - as soon as I learned what  a strong ref. cycle was I've always tried to work "inside out" in fear of having two objects locked into existence but this makes all the sense in the world.

Comment: Delegates are weak references to avoid reference cycles. Otherwise a view controller would own a table view, and the table view would own it's delegate, and you'd get a retain cycle. The basic rule is that in situation where 2 objects point to each other, one of those references should be weak.